# Save an object as a .R file within R, keeping formatting

Tags: r

I am writing an R script that reads in a template .R file, a list of dates, and creates a bunch of folders corresponding to the dates and containing copes of the .R wherein text substitution has been performed in R to customize each script for the given date.

I'm stuck on the part where I write out the .R file though, because the formatting and/or character representation keeps getting screwed up.

Here's a minimal, reproducible example:

```
RMapsDemo <- readLines("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hack-r/RMapsDemo/master/RMapsDemo.R")
RMapsDemo <- gsub("## File: RMapsDemo.R", "## File: RMapsDemo.R ####", RMapsDemo)
save(RMapsDemo, file = "RMapsDemo.R")            # Doesn't work right
save(RMapsDemo, file = "RMapsDemo.R", ascii = T) # Doesn't work right
dput(RMapsDemo, file = "RMapsDemo.R")            # Close, but no cigar
dput(RMapsDemo, file = "RMapsDemo.R", control = c("keepNA", "keepInteger")) # Close, but no cigar
```

Comment: have you tried `writeLines()` ?

Comment: @RicardoSaporta Nope, good idea. I'll try it.

Comment: feel free to submit it as an answer, so that others can google it

Comment: @RicardoSaporta Sure, I thought you'd want to do that, but I can do it and give you credit in the answer

Answer (score 1):

Ricardo Saporta pointed out the solution in the comments -- use `writeLines`.

I feel stupid for not thinking of this myself. It works beautifully.

```
writeLines(RMapsDemo, con = "RMapsDemo.R")
```

Comment: @RicardoSaporta argh! Sorry -- fixed it. Richard is the name of someone else I talk to on here a lot. My apologies.